# How to summarize multiple time series like dataset

Tags: pandas, graphs

I am running an experiment where I am sampling CPU utilization every second.

A snippet of the data from each experiment run is something like this:

```
timestamp   cpu1  cpu2  cpu3  cpu4        
1.581015e+09    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1.581015e+09   41.6  57.4  54.5  47.0
1.581015e+09   84.3  72.5  46.6  82.8
1.581015e+09    1.0  83.7   1.0   2.0
1.581015e+09   33.0  43.3  44.4  37.8
```

I am using pandas to explore the data.

To ensure validity of the experiment, I repeat the experiment 20 times.

Now I have 20 of each of the dataset above.

My question now, is what is the best strategy to:

1. Summarize the data.
2. Graph a summary of the data

If I only had one run, I would like to graph the data in a line chat, but now that I have 20, not sure how to proceed.

Find the average at each second across all the 20 dataset? Or is there any recommended approach to handling this?

Comment: Do you mean the average of the 4 cpus at each timestamp? I am a bit confused because it looks like the timestamp is the same at each row. Can you provide more data, adding in what the next experiment would look like with a label for each row denoting the trial number?

Answer (score 1):

That depends what you want to show and how much information fits in the graph. Typically you can think of:

- Simply using a different colour for every dataset, but 20 is probably too many and that will make the graph hard to read.
- Using boxplots (or violin plots) at every instant, where the boxplot represents the 20 values of the dataset.